# Is there a function to check the same value in range?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I am using google sheets and I have a query that if the value in the range is the same then write something. If at least value is other from rest. Can somebody have an idea how to bite this topic?

I was trying to use

```
=if(A2:C2="Something";"YES";"NO")
```

---

```
=if(A2="Something" AND B2="Something";"YES";"NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
if(column(range)*row(range)=countif(range;index(range;0;0);"YES";"NO")
```

The first part calculates the number of cells in the range, the second calculates the
number of values equal to the value in the first cell.

You can replace the condition by changing index(range;0;0) to for example "Something", if you want to match a literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>""; IF(COUNTIF(A1:A; A1:A)>1; "yes"; "no"); ))
```

[image]